# How to fix random lines that appear in my background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When player move left to right, random blue lines appear.

[image]

Comment: That's likely caused by some inexact rounding when your textures are mapped. (These are not blue lines, but gaps between tiles, where you can see the background)

Answer (score 1):

As I can see this lines are coming because your terrain sprites are not properly aligned. there is Gap between two connected sprites which is not visible in Game scene but can be visible in while playing.